# Please correct this implementation of unique row selection (drop duplicates)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to select unique rows from a JOINed table

(ignore any duplicates except one fitting the criteria)

where duplicate is defined by records having identical values in the column `post_title`

the row with the lowest value in the `_meta_value` column from each duplicate set is to be selected.  If it's a tie between 2 rows, then just take the row with the lowest `post_ID` or `ID` (unique).

So far this is what I have - it doesn't work (returns zero rows) - and while the intention should be clear, I'm certain I'm not using the correct functions.

```
SELECT * FROM (

select wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_type, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value
      from wp_postmeta JOIN wp_posts 
ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID

WHERE post_type = 'product' AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
    GROUP BY post_title
 ) as alias1
HAVING MIN(meta_value)

ORDER BY post_title
```

Here is the minimum data sample requested after the `JOIN` of the two tables:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| wp_posts.ID | wp_posts.post_title | wp_postmeta.post_id | wp_posts.post_type | wp_postmeta.meta_key | wp_postmeta.meta_value |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
|           1 | Apple Pie           |                   1 | Product            | _regular_price       |                     10 |
|           2 | French Toast        |                   2 | Product            | _regular_price       |                      5 |
|           3 | Shepards Pie        |                   3 | Product            | _regular_price       |                      9 |
|           4 | Jam Pie             |                   4 | Product            | _regular_price       |                      8 |
|           5 | Jam Pie             |                   5 | Product            | _regular_price       |                     11 |
|           9 | French Toast        |                   9 | Product            | _regular_price       |                     12 |
|          10 | French Toast        |                  10 | Product            | _regular_price       |                     12 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

The query should return:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| wp_posts.ID | wp_posts.post_title | wp_postmeta.post_id | wp_posts.post_type | wp_postmeta.meta_key | wp_postmeta.meta_value |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
|           1 | Apple Pie           |                   1 | Product            | _regular_price       |                     10 |
|           2 | French Toast        |                   2 | Product            | _regular_price       |                      5 |
|           3 | Shepards Pie        |                   3 | Product            | _regular_price       |                      9 |
|           4 | Jam Pie             |                   4 | Product            | _regular_price       |                      8 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: For next time, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: MySql 5.x or 8.x? I'm asking this because this is a lot easier to do using a window function like ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @Lukstorms On my test server MyPHPAdmin says `Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution`, on my production server MyPHPAdmin says `Server version: 5.7.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Indeed.  That means you need a SQL that works for 5.7. Which doesn't have CTE's nor window functions.  (But MariaDB 10 does)

Comment: @Strawberry I've provided a data set above to address your concerns.

Comment: You've provided data, but you haven't addressed my concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the duplicate based on  your filter (where)  for post_title  using group by and having count(*) > 1

```
select wp_posts.post_title
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
Group by wp_posts.post_title 
having count(*) > 1
```

you can obtain the min id for these duplicated  using

```
select wp_posts.post_title, min(wp_posts.ID)
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
Group by wp_posts.post_title 
having count(*) > 1
```

You should not add  column ad the query ..this is some version  of mysql raise error and in others produce impredictable result
instead you should use the  aggregated  result with min(id)  as a subquery for join the values you need

```
select wp_posts.ID
    , wp_posts.post_title
    , wp_postmeta.post_id
    , wp_posts.post_type
    , wp_postmeta.meta_key
    , wp_postmeta.meta_value
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID 
inner join  (
 select wp_posts.post_title, min(wp_posts.ID) min_id 
    from wp_postmeta 
    JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
        WHERE post_type = 'product' 
        AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
    Group by wp_posts.post_title 
    having count(*) > 1

) t ON t.min_id  = wp_posts.ID  
        and  t.post_title = wp_posts.post_title
```

but if you want all the first value for post_title indipendently of the fact the title is duplicated  or not (as in your sample)  then  avoid the clause HAVING count(*) >1

```
select wp_posts.ID
, wp_posts.post_title
, wp_postmeta.post_id
, wp_posts.post_type
, wp_postmeta.meta_key
, wp_postmeta.meta_value
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID 
inner join  (
  select wp_posts.post_title, min(wp_posts.ID) min_id 
  from wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
  Group by wp_posts.post_title 


 ) t ON t.min_id  = wp_posts.ID  
    and  t.post_title = wp_posts.post_title
```

Seems that the question is change respect min(wp_posts.ID)   to  p_postmeta.meta_value

```
select wp_posts.ID
, wp_posts.post_title
, wp_postmeta.post_id
, wp_posts.post_type
, wp_postmeta.meta_key
, wp_postmeta.meta_value
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID 
inner join  (
  select wp_posts.post_title, min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) min_val
  from wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
  Group by wp_posts.post_title 


 ) t ON t.min_val  = wp_postmeta.meta_value
    and  t.post_title = wp_posts.post_title
```

and for exclude the second row for the  same meta_value 
use min(id)

```
select wp_posts.ID
, wp_posts.post_title
, min( wp_postmeta.post_id)
, wp_posts.post_type
, wp_postmeta.meta_key
, wp_postmeta.meta_value
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID 
inner join  (
  select wp_posts.post_title, min(wp_postmeta.meta_value) min_val
  from wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
  Group by wp_posts.post_title 


 ) t ON t.min_val  = wp_postmeta.meta_value
    and  t.post_title = wp_posts.post_title 
 group by  wp_posts.ID
, wp_posts.post_title
, wp_posts.post_type
, wp_postmeta.meta_key
, wp_postmeta.meta_value
```

Comment: Something is wrong.  When I use `min(wp_metadata.meta_key)` in line 1 of your second code block, some rows are returned with an empty values for `meta_key`.  Is this what you expect?  (The original `wp_metadata.meta_key` contains no empty values.)

Comment: Based  on your sample my query should not return empty values for meta_key  ... meta_key should be only  = '_regular_price' ..  what query you are using  ..  ???

Comment: `select wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_type, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value, COUNT(wp_posts.post_title) AS c
from wp_postmeta 
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'product' 
    AND meta_key = '_regular_price'
Group by wp_posts.post_title 
having count(c) > 1`  I'm lost - I really don't know what I'm doing at this point...

Comment: By the way, empty values for `meta_value`, not `meta_key` - I mispoke.  The minimum example is not the same as my product database which is what I ran the query on...  I need to study your code for a bit, I'm really new at this...  Will reply asap

Comment: Forgive me if I have done something wrong - this query only returns two rows: `2 French Toast 2 Product _regular_price 5` and
`4 Jam Pie 4 Product _regular_price 8`.  Is this what you expected?  The solution should contain 4 rows, shouldn't it? As in the original post.

Comment: if you want only the duplicated  rows  the correct result should be  row 2 and 4 .. otherwise if you want the firts row  for all the post_title the you obtain  1,2,3 ,4   in this case you don't need  the clause having  ...answer  updated .. hope is clear

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - I want the one instance of `post_title` which contains the row with the smallest value for `meta_key`.  If there are multiple rows meeting this criteria, then just take the instance with the lowest `post_ID` or `ID`.

Comment: Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed7229bf40384dfcd68fb6d997c62214).  This doesn't pick out the row with the lowest `meta_value` from each duplicate set?  I changed the `meta_values` of the last two rows to `1` to make this point.

Comment: Answer  udpated .. for meta_value  ..but yiou have two result for the same min_value anyway this seems strange  in your first question you are looking for min_id  ..    .. so  .. i'm disapponted ..  seems that you have change the question  .. otherwise why two answer mine and the answer  below are refered for min_id ??

Comment: Right, in this case, what I intended, where there is a tie between `meta_value`s, was to fall back to selecting the lowest `ID`.  So there should only be one row for `French Toast`, just use `ID=9` and discard `ID=10` (the lower of the two)

Comment: In fairness, I did add the secondary criteria (select lowest `ID` after `meta_value`) as I forgot to raise the possibility of a tie on `meta_value` in the original question.  I will take the blame for that.  I'm not sure why this is cause to be upset though, I'm not criticising you or purposely moving the goal posts.  I'm agreeing that something should be done about the two French toast rows being returned.  I'll accept your answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can get those results via a simple `GROUP BY` and using `MIN`.

```
SELECT 
 MIN(p.ID) AS ID, 
 p.post_title, 
 MIN(pm.post_id) AS post_id, 
 p.post_type, 
 pm.meta_key, 
 MIN(pm.meta_value) AS meta_value
FROM wp_posts p 
JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (pm.post_ID = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_regular_price')
WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
GROUP BY p.post_title, p.post_type, pm.meta_key
ORDER BY ID;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dd193af2cb089939961f8e21b6d8ea5)*

Comment: This doesn't pick out the row with the lowest `meta_value` from each duplicate set?

Comment: Correct.  Because I didn't think it was needed to get that expected output. You see, the wp_posts.ID will always be same as the wp_postmeta.post_ID because of the INNER JOIN. And the post_title & meta_key are fixed because of the criteria.  So it just needs to get the minimum meta_value.  If you would have needed the wp_postmeta.ID for that minimum, then yes, the query would be different.